# Unable to partition/format a SD card with gdisk/mkfs, is there any other tool available to do so

Tags: partition, opensuse, sd-card

I'm on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2. Reading/writing data to a SD card is very slow. Therefore I decided to partition/format it to resolve the problem. I tried to partition with `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb` but it cannot finish the job and returns `Error 6`.

I tried to format the existing partition on SD card with `sudo mkfs /dev/sdb1` but it cannot finish operation.

Also I tried to run `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` but it runs into read/write errors.

I wonder if there is any other tool to partition/format/erase/whatever the SD card.

Comment: For future reference, you can use Yast -> System -> Partitioner to handle making partitions and formating disks. It helps to verify that you have the correct disk before doing anything to it. Especially as OpenSUSE Leap has been known to reassign the /dev/sd? names during boot process. For now, as @db48x says, sounds like the SD card is dead, or dying, and it's time to replace it.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Thanks for `Yast -> System -> Partitioner`, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting read or write errors, then changing your tools won't help; the disk is bad. If you're reading from a broken disk then a tool like ddrescue can help, but that's not going to help you format it. Get a new disk.